# Why "SELECT DISTINCT" with HSQLDB not working?

Tags: select, distinct, hsqldb, jdbctemplate

I have a problem. When I try to use the "Select distinct" in HSQLDB, the stream of results returns me all rows instead of me returning only distinct rows.

I've tried the following syntax:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT FROM ratings UserID order by UserID;
SELECT DISTINCT (UserID) FROM ratings order by UserID;
SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM ratings;
SELECT DISTINCT (UserID) FROM ratings;
```

None of them works. What is the problem?

If anyone able to help me I appreciate.
Thank you.

The function code where I perform the action is as follows:

```java
private void readUserFile(String filename) {

    try {

        //Verify if file users exists
        boolean exists = (new File(filename)).exists();

        if (!exists) {
            //If file users not exists create one, bases on distinct users that exist in ratings table 

            ResultSet rsUsers = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM ratings order by UserID;");

            List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (rsUsers.next()) {

                users.add(String.valueOf(rsUsers.getInt(1)));                  
            }

            rsUsers.close();

            //Create and write to file
            BufferedWriter f = null;
            f = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

            for (String user : users) {
                f.write(user);
                f.newLine();
            }
            f.close();

        }

        PreparedStatement prstInsert = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?)");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            String s = in.readLine();
            if (s == null) { // end of file 
                log.info("Total imported users: " + i);
                break;
            }
            i++;

            int userid = Integer.parseInt(s);
            prstInsert.setInt(1, userid);

            if (i != 0 && Math.round((double) i / 100) == ((double) i / 100)) {
                log.info("Imported users: " + i);
            }
            prstInsert.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the CREATE TABLE statement and any CREATE INDEX statement for this table, plus report the HSQLDB version.